# Geometrical Combinatorics About Rectangles

Tags: probability, combinatorics, geometry, contest-math

Part of a olympiad problem

[image: ruby gagshire]

The answer is $$441 = 21^2$$

I fail to understand why. How do you solve this? I actually dont see why there are $9$ rectangles there either? Can someone give me a hand?

Comment: It says rectangle but not square, like, 2 neighbor squares form a rectangle.

Comment: I wonder, How are there 9 rectangles in the eg? Its a screenshot so I dont think there is an error by the OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the rectangle with vertices at $(x_1,y_1), (x_2,y_1), (x_1,y_2)$ and $(x_2,y_2)$. We see that picking a rectangle is the same as picking integers $0 \leq x_1 < x_2 \leq 6$ and $0 \leq y_1 < y_2 \leq 6$ (with $6$ replaced by $2$ in the smaller example). So there are ${7 \choose 2}^2 = 21^2 = 441$ rectangles.

A picture of what's happening:

[image]

Comment: I sort of see it. There are $7$ vertices available. Then you only choose $2$ of them to get $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ Later This is only for one edge. The other one is the same. So: $$\binom{7}{2}^2$$ But this says if you have 7 options, how many ways are there to choose two of them. How does this show how many rectangles there are though?

Comment: For each side, we have to pick two out of the seven points, namely a beginning and an end point.

Comment: But $$\binom{7}{2}$$ Represents how many ways there are to choose $2$ vertices from the $7$ choices right? So: $$\binom{7}{2}^2$$ Means how many ways there are to choose two vertices on each side? But how does that show how many rectangles can be made?

Comment: Check the picture I added to my answer. I hope this shows how picking two points on both sides produces a rectangle.